# android: content observer onchange method is called when chating on whatsapp

Tags: android

I used contact observer in my application to observe contacts changes and it keeps calling the onchange method when using whatsapp,is there a way to avoid these extra calls?(I have already override deliverSelfNotifications())

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Show what have you tried so far. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for inspiration

Answer (score 0):

Your `onChange` method is called because the contacts data actually gets changed, this is expected behavior.

When sending a message on Whatsapp (and in many other apps as well), the contact's `TIMES_CONTACTED` and `LAST_TIME_CONTACTED` values are updated which triggers onChange notifications to all observers.

ContentObserver doesn't support specifying type of changes to will trigger and some that will not, so your app gets called for all type of changes.

You need to keep some local copy (preferably a simple hash value) that represents only interesting fields in the contacts data, then, when you `onChange` method gets called, query for contacts that had been modified recently (use [CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP) for that) and compare the previous hash to the new hash value, if different you know that contact had been changed.

Here's an example query you could use:

```
private void fetchRecentContacts(long lastTimeChecked) {
    String[] projection = new String[] { Contacts._ID, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP }; // add more relevant fields here
    String selection = Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP + " > " + lastTimeChecked;
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cur);

    // iterate cursor and check for changes

    cur.close();
}
```